# Is nikon Z6 a good replacement for D750 on outdoors photojournalism?

Tags: nikon, equipment-recommendation, nikon-d750

We're looking for a replacement to our worn-out Nikon D750. Our budget limits us to two choices: another D750 or a Z6.

We know about the many advantages Z6 has over D750, but don't know if it's equally resistant to heavy use. We usually carry our camera out to harsh environments, and shoot about 1.000 stills daily. Usually fast-continuous shooting. Would Z6 handle that as D750 does?

Another point is lens compatibility. I assume we can pair Z6 to our Nikon F 24-70mm F2.8 G ED and Nikon 70-200mm F2.8 G ED VR with the FTZ adapter and it will work as usual, but I'd like to hear some real-life experience of it, just to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

The two significant disadvantages of the Z6 compared to the D750 are considerably shorter battery life and only a single memory card. If you don't mind buying/carrying a few spare batteries and don't need to use two cards to record each image on both cards for redundancy, then the only other major issue you have mentioned regarding the Z6 is build quality and reliability.

As far as toughness/weather resistance/reliability goes, it's still way too early to judge that and the jury is still out on the Z6 at this point in time.

Otherwise, the Z6 outperforms the D750 in many measurable metrics. It has a much deeper buffer that allows longer raw bursts before the buffer fills.

There are [some reports](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4P_FgAjYKA) that the "hit rate" is not as good in continuous AF with the Z6 as compared to the D750. Which would work better for you depends on whether you would rather have fewer images with 90% in focus or a lot more images with 60-70% in focus. [Tony Northrup claimed](https://youtu.be/LLeOu18lXTw?t=1133) he only got about 2.5 frames per second that were actually in focus when using the Z6 at 12 fps.